# C# Subscribing an Event

Tags: c#

I have the following code with 3 different classes. I am trying to 
Subscribe event from class B to method (event handler) defined in 
class ControlSystem. All compiles fine, it works no problem but the event handler method is never triggered...  What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace EventTest
{
    public class ControlSystem : CrestronControlSystem
    {
        A myObject = new A();

        public ControlSystem(): base()
        {
            Thread.MaxNumberOfUserThreads = 100;

            // Subscribe Event
            myObject.mySubObject.BEvent += HandleBEvent;

            // Throw Event
            myObject.mySubObject.ThrowEvent();

        }
        public override void InitializeSystem()
        {

        }

        public void HandleBEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something happend to {0}", sender);
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public B mySubObject;

        public A()
        {
            mySubObject = new B();
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public EventHandler BEvent;

        public B(){}

        public void ThrowEvent()
        {
            EventHandler handler = BEvent;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Real code links below (it works with Embeded system so you won't be able to compile it). Idea is to have button press to trigger an event which could
alarm other UIs that something happend to it.

http://ideone.com/NJz2Ek

Thanks

Comment: When do you want the event to get triggered?

Comment: Code works for me. [Check yourself](http://ideone.com/1eEhfF). You need to provide a code which reproduces the problem you're talking about.

Comment: So, then there is no problem ?

Comment: I suspect this is a 'simplified' version of the real code. The missing `event` keyword could cause a subscription to be lost, but not here.

Comment: I think you're right there @HenkHolterman; despite `event` not being used - seems likely to me in the real code that one of these subobjects is being re-newed after the 'subscription' is created (just not in this specific example)

Comment: @HenkHolterman I suspect the same. The event keyword needs to be there most likely to solve the real issue in the real code. I would put the event keyword here too, because it shows intent.

Comment: Intent and encapsulation. Adding the `event` kw probably causes a syntax error where the real problem now is.

Comment: @ArkadiuszRycyk - edit your question with a real code sample that reproduces the error.

Comment: Done. It's somehing that runs on embeded systems so you won't be able to compile it unfortunetly...

Comment: The relevant code should be part of the question, not an external link. I had a quick look but it doesn't seem complete. So you just haven't asked the right question to get a meaningful answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the event keyword.

```
public event EventHandler BEvent;
```

is what needs to be there.

Comment: But that's not the problem. OP's code works. Without the event keyword, event is treated as delegate which is fine.

Comment: Yes, it's a good catch but not the core problem. `BEvent` is a public field now.